# Popup window blocks test in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, pde

I'm running the pde test in ant build with parameter:

`-application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication`.

When the eclipse instance is started while running the test, it pops up a dialog window (named "Usage Data Upload") which blocks the test run until I manually close it.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude bundles **com.instantiations.eclipse.usageprofiler** and **com.instantiations.eclipse.usageprofiler.ui** from your product.